# join two query with avg in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, query-builder

I have this:

```
$avgOfCourse = StudyArgument::where('course_id', '=', 2)->select(DB::raw('date avgDate ,round(avg(study),1) avgStudy , round(avg(argument),1) avgArgument'))->groupBy('date')->get();
```

and the result is:

```
avgDate       |   avgStudy  |   avgArgument
1992-08-16    |   250.0     |   250.0
2022-01-10    |   150.0     |   200.0
2022-02-03    |   350.0     |   350.0
```

And then i have this:

```
$studyArgumentOfUser = DB::table('study_arguments', 'users')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->select('date', 'study', 'argument')->get();
```

The result is

```
date          |   study |   argument
2022-01-10    |   200   |   300
2022-01-01    |   150   |   150
1992-08-16    |   250   |   250
2022-02-03    |   350   |   350
```

Now I want to merge these two queries
like this:

```
   avgDate       |   avgStudy  |   avgArgument  |   study |   argument
    1992-08-16    |   250.0     |   250.0       |   250   |   250
    2022-01-10    |   150.0     |   200.0       |   200   |   300
    2022-02-03    |   350.0     |   350.0       |   350   |   350
```

How can I get this result from the above queries?

Comment: If possible share table structure of users and study_arguments.

Comment: `Schema::create('study_arguments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')-onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->integer('study')->nullable();
            $table->integer('argument')->nullable();
            $table->date('date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });`

Comment: `Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });`

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::create('study_arguments', function (Blueprint $table) {             $table->id();             $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');             $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');             $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');             $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')-onUpdate('cascade');             $table->integer('study')->nullable();             $table->integer('argument')->nullable();             $table->date('date');             $table->timestamps();         });


Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {              $table->id();             $table->string('name');             $table->string('email')->unique();             $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();             $table->string('password');             $table->rememberToken();             $table->timestamps();         });
```